# decode string from smart contract

Tags: solidity, javascript

I have an event that fires from a function which receives a string as parameter, this string is a GUID.
However when I use web3.getpastevents it looks like my string(GUID) is encoded as hex, but when I try to decode using hexToUtf8 I get the following error "Uncaught Error: Invalid continuation byte".

How can I decode GUID from my smart contract event log?

Comment: What's the event declaration? Is the string parameter indexed?